# Bluetooth device connection problems

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, bluetooth

I have two OS on the same disk, used by my PC — Ubuntu and Windows.
When I pair my bluetooth device on either ubuntu and windows, I can connect it without problems. Then I boot to a different OS (if initially I paired the device on ubuntu, then I boot to windows and vice-versa) and pair the device and again I can connect it. However, when I boot back to the OS where I first paired the device, I can't connect it. I find that then I have to remove it, pair it again and then I can connect.
But the problem remains that each time when I boot into different OS (on the same PC), I have to redo this annoying procedure.
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: This is not a trivial or easy thing to achieve. Pairing is handled by the OS and headset and it depends on things in both. Some options at https://superuser.com/search?q=dual+boot+pair+bluetooth#

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem using the link Mokubai provided in the comments, under the question.
The link: [How to use bluetooth devices under two different operation systems?](https://superuser.com/questions/422435/how-to-use-bluetooth-devices-under-two-different-operation-systems)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).